# Use Generics of Other Class for Generic Typing

Tags: java, generics

I have a class

```
public class A<K, T> {
    K myk;
    T myt;
}
```

An inherited class looks like the following

```
public class AExtended extends A<Integer,String>{}
```

Now I would like to re-use the types of a `AExtended`, I am looking for something like this:´

```
public class B<? extends A<K,T>> {  //does not work
    K myInt;
    T MyString;

    public static void createB() {
        var b=new B<AExtended>(); //does also not work
    }

}
```

I know, I cloud do the following, but I don't want to re-type all the types of `AExtended`. Instead, I want to re-use the types of `AExtended`!

```
public class B<L extends A<K,T>,K,T> {
    K myInt;
    T MyString;

    public static void createB() {
        var b=new B<AExtended,Integer,String>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: A and B should not have an extends relation

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem: what are you trying to do with this? Seeing what you're trying to do could help somebody see an alternative.